# keep an input field a controlled component

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I've a component with a state object initialized like this :

```
this.state = {
    item: {}
}
```

`item` is an object that will be populated from the DB (via `API` call). Then item.name is connected to a form field like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.item.name} />
```

Everything is OK, but the problem comes when I need to RESET the `item` object.

I want the `resetItem()` function below to reset the whole `item` state object, but when I call it after the form is populated once via the API, the input value doesn't change, it keeps the last value, because the input field was trying to change from a `controlled` field to `uncontrolled`.

```
resetItem(){
    this.setState({ item: {} }); //DOESN't work, the input value is not cleared
}
```

The only way to get it working is if I clean all the object properties, one by one. Which is not what I want.

```
resetItem(){
    this.setState({ item: { name: '', address: '' } }); //Works, but it's not what I want
}
```

Demo :
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/240720/)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Why was my question title and content edited @Mohammadreza Panahi???

Comment: to reach a broader audience, when running your code, you get a warning message "changing from uncontrolled to a controlled" element. Most people will search that instead of what you titled.

Comment: which was how I debugged your code in the first place, through that warning message.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51509274/revisions) to understand why your question edited.

Comment: Strange, didn't know about SO revisions. But ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with when an `input` field goes from un-controlled component to a controlled component. When you provide input field with nothing, it defaults to un-controlled component.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/240731/

To keep a component within controlled, use a simple hack

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.item.name? this.state.item.name : ""} />
```

Comment: Wow, such a great tip. I wasn't aware of this. Thanks @leogoesger 